# Creating a new class c++ in Unreal with Visual Studio gives me too many errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4

I have a problem with creating new c++ classes. For example, a did a Player controller and it compiles but when it is open in Visual Studio, it says there are too many errors for the IntelliSense to function properly. My Unreal Engine version is 4.25 and visual studio 2019 version 16.6.2

Then it gets crazy in the Error List with 15390 errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformTLS.h"  TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\PlatformTLS.h 8   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformTime.h" TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\PlatformTime.h    7   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformString.h"   TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\PlatformString.h  6   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformProperties.h"   TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\PlatformProperties.h  11  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformProcess.h"  TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\PlatformProcess.h 7   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformMisc.h" TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\PlatformMisc.h    7   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformMemory.h"   TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\PlatformMemory.h  7   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformMath.h" TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\PlatformMath.h    7   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformAtomics.h"  TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\PlatformAtomics.h 8   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformCompilerSetup.h"    TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\Platform.h    1024    
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatform.h" TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\Platform.h    135 
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformCompilerPreSetup.h" TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\Platform.h    81  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMCriticalSection.h"  TestingCode C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\CriticalSection.h 7
```

Comment: Your first step is to look at the errors from the top verify if the path exists. Can not open source file should be something you can check using your OS file explorer.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to a VS solution folder. Delete following folders : ".vs", "Intermediate", "Saved"
2. Delete solution (*.sln file). Keep *.uproject
3. Right click on *.uproject in explorer, click "switch unreal engine versoin" and select your current engine version. Project files and solutions will get regenerated.
4. Open your vs solution. Your generated files will be missing, so hit "build" button.
5. Go to Tools->Options->Text editor->Advanced, set "Recreate Database" to "true" and restart visual studio
6. Wait and pray for it to work (worked for me tho)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26476247)

Comment: Edited to contain possible solution

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this nearly daily. My advice is not to rely on IntelliSense when it comes to errors and change the "Errors" window in Visual Studio to just display "Build only" errors.

When you build, you'll only get the real errors that are actually messing up your build. Because the UnrealHeaderTool actually creates a lot of code in the background, some things are not available when creating a new class or refactoring methods.

A best practice seems to be to just rely on what MSBuild gives you, instead of waiting for IntelliSense to catch up. Fixing an error like "could not find this file" or "undefined type" from the compiler should be way easier than trying to tell IntelliSense to understand that there exist macros that are not Preprocessor-macros, but UHT macros.

If you just stick to the Build errors, the problem will go away at some point. At least for me it did.

Also note that the unity build that Unreal uses, may break files you did not even work on, because you forgot an include that was already there when the build tool merged the files in the last build.